# How does the wheel speed sensor in a Boeing 777-300ER work?

Tags: aircraft-systems, landing-gear, boeing-777

I do have a maintenance manual that I found on Internet, but it doesn't have anything about the wheel speed transducer.

Any pics along with the information would be helpful.

Answer (score 6):

From [this Aviation Studies project report](https://anoukaviation.files.wordpress.com/2009/07/project-report-landing-gear.pdf) of group 2A2I at the University of applied Sciences in Amsterdam, for a Boeing 777-200:

> Every wheel is equipped with an anti-skid transducer (appendix VII),
>   which is installed in the axle. The transducer consists of a rotor and
>   stator. According to the speed of rotation, an electrical signal is
>   send to the BSCU.
>
> This computer compares the rotation speed of all the
>   wheels and detects when a wheel is rotating slower than the other
>   wheels on the MLG. The BSCU will send a signal to reduce braking power
>   when the rotation speed of one wheel reduces more in comparison to
>   other wheels.

The principle is the wheel axle drives a permanent magnet within a 3-phase winding. The frequency of the signal generated is proportional to the wheel angular speed.

From B777 General Familiarization Manual:

[image]
<sup>Antiskid and Autobrake Diagram, [source](http://www.aviationlearning.net/files/B777%20REFRESHER%20GE%20RR.pdf)</sup>

Note: I initially believed the tacho-generator was a Socitec ST80, the same than on A320 (part number is C20105000). However when I wanted to provide a supporting document, I couldn't. So please take this as an assumption only until someone provides the part number from a Boeing document (I don't think there would be a big difference between B777 and A320 tacho-generator anyway).

[image]
[image]
<sup>Tacho-generator, part C20105000, [source](https://www.ebay.at/itm/Airbus-A320-Tachometer-P-N-C20105000-As-Removed-/252033983332)</sup>

More information: [Bodet Aero](http://www.circoraerospace.com/downloads/bodet/Bodet-AC-Tachometers-ST-Series.pdf). According to Bodet Aero, their tachometer equips A300, A310, A319, A320, A321, A330 and A340.

More about tachometers: [TheAirlinePilots](https://www.theairlinepilots.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=927) (section "Three Phase AC Electrical Tachometer").

This is a typical installation of the transducer (not a particular aircraft):

[image]
<sup>[Source](http://en.digivideofestmenyek.com/hobby/aviation/aviation-dictionary/f-l)</sup>

Comment: I know how a tachogeneartor operates and thought B777 uses one too but my supervisor said Tachogenerators aren't used in any latest aircraft, they use an auto transformer to do the same.

Comment: An additional search shows that these transducers are made by [Crane/Hydro-Aire](http://www.craneae.com/Products/Landing/Antiskid.aspx), and have part nr [140-025-1, 140-025-2, 140-025100 and 140-025101](https://www.aerospaceunlimited.com/aircraft-repair/commercial-aircraft-by-model/b777-all-series/). But no details on the technology used.